# trying to create jar file but have some errors

Tags: java, maven, heroku, jar, spring-boot

I downloaded [this repository from GitHub](https://github.com/jirkapinkas/java-blog-aggregator-boot), and make some changes. Now I want to deploy this on the Heroku. But when I try to make jar file, I have some errors. Maybe someone know what is the problem and how to fix it?

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building java-blog-aggregator-boot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ jba ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 76 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ jba ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ jba ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 9 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ jba ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ jba ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\java-blog-aggregator-boot-master\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.AllTests
16:18:13,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
16:18:13,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
16:18:13,179 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/Username/Desktop/java-blog-aggregator-boot-master/target/classes/logback.xml]
16:18:13,331 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
16:18:13,353 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
16:18:13,397 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
16:18:13,602 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - This appender no longer admits a layout as a sub-component, set an encoder instead.
16:18:13,602 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - To ensure compatibility, wrapping your layout in LayoutWrappingEncoder.
16:18:13,602 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[STDOUT] - See also http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#layoutInsteadOfEncoder for details
16:18:13,603 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
16:18:13,607 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [FILE]
16:18:13,660 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - No compression will be used
16:18:13,663 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy - Will use the pattern debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
16:18:13,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4d3167f4 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern 'debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log'.
16:18:13,670 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4d3167f4 - Roll-over at midnight.
16:18:13,820 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@4d3167f4 - Setting initial period to Thu Jun 02 16:17:02 EEST 2016
16:18:13,825 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - Active log file name: debug.log
16:18:13,825 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - File property is set to [debug.log]
16:18:13,827 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
16:18:13,827 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [FILE] to Logger[ROOT]
16:18:13,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
16:18:13,828 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
16:18:13,829 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@ed9d034 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

Tests run: 21, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.003 sec <<< FAILURE! - in cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.AllTests
testGetItemsFileJavaVids(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.189 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<23 03 2014 [09]:01:34> but was:<23 03 2014 [10]:01:34>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileJavaVids(RssServiceTest.java:59)

testGetItemsFileHibernate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.392 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<04 04 2014 1[7]:20:32> but was:<04 04 2014 1[8]:20:32>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileHibernate(RssServiceTest.java:84)

testGetItemsFileSpring(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.475 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<07 04 2014 1[0]:14:00> but was:<07 04 2014 1[1]:14:00>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileSpring(RssServiceTest.java:70)

testGetRssDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Sun Mar 23 [09:01:34 C]ET 2014> but was:<Sun Mar 23 [10:01:34 E]ET 2014>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetRssDate(RssServiceTest.java:120)

testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 1.005 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<22 02 2015 1[3]:35:00> but was:<22 02 2015 1[4]:35:00>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate(RssServiceTest.java:184)

Running cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.BlogServiceTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec - in cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.BlogServiceTest
Running cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.ItemServiceTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec - in cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.ItemServiceTest
Running cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest
Tests run: 18, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.979 sec <<< FAILURE! - in cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest
testGetItemsFileJavaVids(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<23 03 2014 [09]:01:34> but was:<23 03 2014 [10]:01:34>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileJavaVids(RssServiceTest.java:59)

testGetItemsFileHibernate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.108 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<04 04 2014 1[7]:20:32> but was:<04 04 2014 1[8]:20:32>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileHibernate(RssServiceTest.java:84)

testGetItemsFileSpring(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.249 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<07 04 2014 1[0]:14:00> but was:<07 04 2014 1[1]:14:00>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileSpring(RssServiceTest.java:70)

testGetRssDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<Sun Mar 23 [09:01:34 C]ET 2014> but was:<Sun Mar 23 [10:01:34 E]ET 2014>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetRssDate(RssServiceTest.java:120)

testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.443 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<22 02 2015 1[3]:35:00> but was:<22 02 2015 1[4]:35:00>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:115)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate(RssServiceTest.java:184)

Running cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.scheduled.ScheduledTasksServiceTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.141 sec - in cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.scheduled.ScheduledTasksServiceTest

Results :

Failed tests: 
cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileHibernate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)
  Run 1: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileHibernate:84 expected:<04 04 2014 1[7]:20:32> but was:<04 04 2014 1[8]:20:32>
  Run 2: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileHibernate:84 expected:<04 04 2014 1[7]:20:32> but was:<04 04 2014 1[8]:20:32>

cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)
  Run 1: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate:184 expected:<22 02 2015 1[3]:35:00> but was:<22 02 2015 1[4]:35:00>
  Run 2: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileInstanceofJavaPublishedDate:184 expected:<22 02 2015 1[3]:35:00> but was:<22 02 2015 1[4]:35:00>

cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileJavaVids(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)
  Run 1: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileJavaVids:59 expected:<23 03 2014 [09]:01:34> but was:<23 03 2014 [10]:01:34>
  Run 2: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileJavaVids:59 expected:<23 03 2014 [09]:01:34> but was:<23 03 2014 [10]:01:34>

cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileSpring(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)
  Run 1: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileSpring:70 expected:<07 04 2014 1[0]:14:00> but was:<07 04 2014 1[1]:14:00>
  Run 2: RssServiceTest.testGetItemsFileSpring:70 expected:<07 04 2014 1[0]:14:00> but was:<07 04 2014 1[1]:14:00>

cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest.testGetRssDate(cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.RssServiceTest)
  Run 1: RssServiceTest.testGetRssDate:120 expected:<Sun Mar 23 [09:01:34 C]ET 2014> but was:<Sun Mar 23 [10:01:34 E]ET 2014>
  Run 2: RssServiceTest.testGetRssDate:120 expected:<Sun Mar 23 [09:01:34 C]ET 2014> but was:<Sun Mar 23 [10:01:34 E]ET 2014>


Tests run: 41, Failures: 5, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.344 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-02T16:18:18+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/268M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project jba: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\Username\Desktop\java-blog-aggregator-boot-master\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Have you looked at the date/time comparisons in the mentioned `test...` methods in the source of `cz.jiripinkas.jba.service.AllTests`?

Comment: I pupblished test files here. Can you check it?

Comment: i facing same problem,how you resolved

Comment: also i can't create new blog in this application

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your unit tests are failing, which will cause the maven build to fail. You can skip tests while running the maven build, or do the right thing and fix the unit tests. They seems like they are failing because of some date?

Comment: How I can skip tests?

Comment: mvn -DskipTests=true clean package  But if there are failing tests,  the app may fail at startup..FYI.

Comment: Then I skip tests I finally create jar file. But when I deploy it on heroku, application is not working. Just show error Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: Log - 2016-06-02T16:33:46.487714+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rssnewsreaderr.herokuapp.com request_id=5ba1e1d9-d801-4fef-8248-e052fb8ad523 fwd="185.138.228.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Usually it is not good practice to skip tests. Tests are made to show you an error in your code so maybe the code itself has an issue. Do you know why are your tests failing?